# How to change the default backend in matplotlib from 'QtAgg' to 'Qt5Agg' in Pycharm?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm, pyqt5, mayavi

`Qt5Agg` is necessary to use the `mayavi` 3D visualization package. I have installed `PyQt5` and `mayavi` using pip in a separate copied `conda` environment. The default backend then changes from `TkAgg` to `QtAgg`. This is a bit weird because in an earlier installation in a different PC the default changed directly to `Qt5Agg`. I always check the backend using the following commands from the python console :

```
import matplotlib 
matplotlib.get_backend()
```

Even with the backend being 'QtAgg', I am able to use `mayavi` from the terminal without any issue but not when I do so in Pycharm. Here I get a non-responsive empty window (image below) :

[Image of the non-responsive window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhjXn.png)

I have been able to get rid of this issue by explicitly using `Qt5Agg` instead of `QtAgg` before the `plt` call :

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

But I would prefer a better way than using the above in every script that I write. As I had mentioned earlier, I already have mayavi installed and have used it successfully it in Pycharm in a different PC and there the default backend is 'Qt5Agg' and hence there is no need to change the backend explicitly.

Is there anything obvious that I'm overlooking ? Can you please let me know of a way to change the default backend for matplotlib from `QtAgg` to `Qt5Agg` after `PyQt5` installation using pip ?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: you can edit the matplotlibrc file https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#customizing-with-matplotlibrc-files

Comment: Thanks a lot @PaulH. I was able to edit the matplotlibrc file and change the default backend. `Qt5Agg` is deprecated in the latest matplotlib update and there was the issue since `mayavi` still uses it.

Comment: @PratikDash If you have fixed it, you can add your own answer how to do this. That way other people can benefit from this question.

Comment: Thank you @mx0 for your comment. I have now answered the question detailing the exact steps that fixed my issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to @PaulH's comment, I was able to solve the issue. Owing to @mx0's suggestion, I shall now explicitly mention the fix below so that others can also benefit from it.

In a particular conda environment, if `matplotlib` package is installed, then there will be a 'matplotlibrc' file stored somewhere that defines what the default backend will be whenever `matplotlib` is imported from that conda environment. The location of this 'matplotlibrc' can be found using the following commands :

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()
```

Please look into the following link if there's any deprecation issue with the above commands :

https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#customizing-with-matplotlibrc-files

Once the location of the 'matplotlibrc' file is known, open it and simply uncomment one line inside this file. Just change the backend from :

```
##backend: Agg
```

to :

```
backend: Qt5Agg
```

And that's it. All the plot window troubles in PyCharm will be solved as far as the `mayavi` 3D visualization package is concerned. For any other use, where a specific backend is necessary, you can also set the default to any other backend of choice.